# MSBuild error when specifying PublishProfile for ASP.NET.Core project

Tags: asp.net-core, msbuild, .net-standard

I have an ASP.NET Core 1.1.2 project targeting .NET Framework  4.6.2. I recently installed the latest version of Visual Studio (15.2 26430.16), and now I can't build the project using MSBuild version 15.1.1012.6693. The error occurs when using a PublishProfile.

The MSBuild command is:

`msbuild D:\project\project.csproj /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=dist`

And the error is:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish\build\netstandard1.0\TransformTargets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.TransformFiles.targets(54,5):
error MSB4062: The "TransformWebConfig" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish\build\netstandard1.0\..\..\tools\net46\\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.Tasks.dll.
Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish\tools\net46\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.Tasks.dll' or one of its dependencies.
An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.
[D:\project\project.csproj]`

It works when not specifying a publish profile. However when publishing the project from Visual Studio, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known bug of the tooling when building using the 64 bit MSBuild version (build server, command line). See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/1073) for details.

Since this issue has been fixed, you need to upgrade to the [recently released 15.3.* versions](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#15.3.26730.03) of Visual Studio / MSBuild and probably also 2.0.0 version of the .NET Core SDK.

Comment: Thanks alot. Upgrading the SDK was enough.